# Data being summed multiple times

Tags: sql, join, sum

Below is the code I am having issue with. Everything worked great until I added the line for "Asian". The information for this had to come from a new table so I had to do a new join. Once I did this I started having problems with the information. The problem is that CDS_MailPlayer can have multiple Mail_ID for the same person. It would then do all the Sum's for each Mail_ID and then add them all together. So if a player was showing $100 Actual but had 2 mail id their Actual would come out as $200. If they had 10 mail id's then their actual would skyrocket to $1000.

How can I add in a check to see if someone has a Mail ID between the range of 161 and 166 while not messing up my math?

Also on a side note is there a way to change the Where clause to pull a rolling 12 months such that if you pulled the report anyday in December of 2014 it would pull 12/1/2013-11/30/2014 but if you pulled the report in Jan of 2015 the date range would change to 1/1/2014-12/31/2014. I got as close as I knew how for know.

And as always any advice on how to clean up the code and make it faster/better would be appreciated still really new to SQL.

Using SQL Server 2000.

```
Select P.Player_ID as "Player ID"
    ,Ltrim(RTrim(P.FirstName)) as "First Name"
    ,Ltrim(RTrim(P.LastName)) as "Last Name"
    ,Convert(char(10),cast(P.Birthday as datetime),101) as "Birthday"
    ,P.EMail as "E-Mail"
    ,Ltrim(RTrim(A.City1)) as "City"
    ,Ltrim(RTrim(A.State1)) as"State"
    ,Ltrim(RTrim(A.Zip1)) as "Zip"
    ,A.BadAddress1
    ,A.CustomFlag3 as "Do Not Mail"
    ,P.LL_Dap_Flag
    ,Round(Sum(S.TWin),2) as Theo
    ,Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)*.75)+
      (Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.CreditIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end)*.4)),2) as Actual
    ,Count(Distinct(S.GamingDate)) as Trips
    ,Count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate)) as Month
    ,Count(Distinct case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.GamingDate end) as "Slot Trips"
    ,Count(Distinct case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then Month(S.GamingDate) end)as "Slot Month"
    ,Count(Distinct case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.GamingDate end) as "Table Trips"
    ,Count(Distinct case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then Month(S.GamingDate) end)as "Table Month"
    ,Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) as ADT
    ,Round(sum(S.Twin)/Nullif(count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate)),0),2) as AMT
    ,Round((((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)*.75)+
      (Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.CreditIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end)*.4))/Nullif(Count(Distinct(S.GamingDate)),0)),2) as ADL
    ,Round((((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)*.75)+
      (Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.CreditIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end)*.4))/Nullif(Count(Distinct Month (S.GamingDate)),0)),2) as AML
    ,case when Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.TWin Else 0 end)>=(Sum(S.TWin)*.8)then 'Table' else 'Slot' end as "Slot/Table"
    ,case when Sum(case when M.Mail_ID between '161' and '166' then 1 else 0 end)>0 Then 'Y' else 'N' end as "Asian"
    ,Case
        When R.Rank_ID = '1' then 'Silver'
        When R.Rank_ID = '2' then 'Gold'
        When R.Rank_ID = '3' then 'Platinum'
        When R.Rank_ID = '4' then 'Diamond'
        Else 'Copper'
    end as "Rank"
    ,P.HostUser_ID
    ,P.Referral

From  dbo.CDS_ACCOUNT as A
    Join dbo.CDS_PLAYER as P
        on A.[Primary_ID] = P.[Player_ID]
    Join dbo.CDS_STATDAY as S
        on A.[Primary_ID] = S.[Meta_ID]
    Join dbo.CDS_MAILPLAYER as M
        on A.[Primary_ID] = M.Player_ID
    Join dbo.Tiered_Rank_Player as R
        on A.[Primary_ID] = R.Player_ID

Where S.GamingDate >= Dateadd(year,-1,getdate())
      And S.IDType = 'P'
      And S.StatType <> 'Poker'
      And A.CustomFlag1 = 'N'  
      And A.CustomFlag2 = 'N'  
      And A.CustomFlag4 = 'N'  
      And A.CustomFlag5 = 'N'  

Group by P.Player_ID
    ,P.FirstName
    ,P.LastName
    ,P.Birthday
    ,P.EMail
    ,A.City1
    ,A.State1
    ,A.Zip1
    ,A.BadAddress1
    ,A.CustomFlag3
    ,P.LL_Dap_Flag
    ,R.Rank_ID
    ,P.HostUser_ID
    ,P.Referral
```

My Solution is below I just changed the line for Asian to a subquery and then removed the associated join and group by from the from select statement.

```
Select P.Player_ID as "Player ID"
    ,Ltrim(RTrim(P.FirstName)) as "First Name"
    ,Ltrim(RTrim(P.LastName)) as "Last Name"
    ,Convert(char(10),cast(P.Birthday as datetime),101) as "Birthday"
    ,P.EMail as "E-Mail"
    ,Ltrim(RTrim(A.City1)) as "City"
    ,Ltrim(RTrim(A.State1)) as"State"
    ,Ltrim(RTrim(A.Zip1)) as "Zip"
    ,A.BadAddress1
    ,A.CustomFlag3 as "Do Not Mail"
    ,P.LL_Dap_Flag
    ,Round(Sum(S.TWin),2) as Theo
    ,Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)*.75)+
      (Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.CreditIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end)*.4)),2) as Actual
    ,Count(Distinct(S.GamingDate)) as Trips
    ,Count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate)) as Month
    ,Count(Distinct case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.GamingDate end) as "Slot Trips"
    ,Count(Distinct case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then Month(S.GamingDate) end)as "Slot Month"
    ,Count(Distinct case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.GamingDate end) as "Table Trips"
    ,Count(Distinct case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then Month(S.GamingDate) end)as "Table Month"
    ,Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) as ADT
    ,Round(sum(S.Twin)/Nullif(count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate)),0),2) as AMT
    ,Round((((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)*.75)+
      (Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.CreditIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end)*.4))/Nullif(Count(Distinct(S.GamingDate)),0)),2) as ADL
    ,Round((((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)*.75)+
      (Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.CreditIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end)*.4))/Nullif(Count(Distinct Month (S.GamingDate)),0)),2) as AML
    ,case when Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.TWin Else 0 end)>=(Sum(S.TWin)*.8)then 'Table' else 'Slot' end as "Slot/Table"
    ,(Select case when Sum(case when M.Mail_ID between '161' and '166' then 1 else 0 end)>0 Then 'Y' else 'N' end as "Asian"
        From dbo.CDS_MAILPLAYER as M) as "Asian"
    ,Case
        When R.Rank_ID = '1' then 'Silver'
        When R.Rank_ID = '2' then 'Gold'
        When R.Rank_ID = '3' then 'Platinum'
        When R.Rank_ID = '4' then 'Diamond'
        Else 'Copper'
    end as "Rank"
    ,P.HostUser_ID
    ,P.Referral

From  dbo.CDS_ACCOUNT as A
    Join dbo.CDS_PLAYER as P
        on A.[Primary_ID] = P.[Player_ID]
    Join dbo.CDS_STATDAY as S
        on A.[Primary_ID] = S.[Meta_ID]
    Join dbo.Tiered_Rank_Player as R
        on A.[Primary_ID] = R.Player_ID

Where S.GamingDate between '12/1/2013' and '11/30/2014'
      And S.IDType = 'P'
      And S.StatType <> 'Poker'
      And A.CustomFlag1 = 'N'  
      And A.CustomFlag2 = 'N'  
      And A.CustomFlag4 = 'N'  
      And A.CustomFlag5 = 'N'  

Group by P.Player_ID
    ,P.FirstName
    ,P.LastName
    ,P.Birthday
    ,P.EMail
    ,A.City1
    ,A.State1
    ,A.Zip1
    ,A.BadAddress1
    ,A.CustomFlag3
    ,P.LL_Dap_Flag
    ,R.Rank_ID
    ,P.HostUser_ID
    ,P.Referral
    ,P.Casino_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these three little changes to fix your primary issue:

1) In the select section:

```
,case when isnull(M.Mail_ID_sp,0) = 0 Then 'N' else 'Y' end as "Asian"
```

2)In the table join section:

```
 left outer Join (SELECT Player_ID, count(*) as Mail_ID_sp FROM dbo.CDS_MAILPLAYER where M.Mail_ID between '161' and '166' GROUP BY Player_ID ) as M
```

3) And finally balance off the group by clause with:

```
,case when isnull(M.Mail_ID_sp,0) = 0 Then 'N' else 'Y' end -- Balancing Group By
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and while it does appear this would work I found a different way to do that makes more sense to my brain. :) I will update my post with what I did.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my original question with the answer I ended up using before I found the button for answering my own question.